# Bootstrap Tour - Initialising two tour in one page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm posting here because I can't find a solution to my problem in the official documentation of Boostrap Tour or in any other topic here.

**Here is my problem :**
I have one page in which I want to initialize two tours in order to give the choice to my user to choose which one start. They are started by a function "StartTour" called by an "onClick" call.

If I declare and initialize my two tours in the same page, when I run the 1st one, on the 3rd step, it switches to the 2nd step of the second tour. The second tour works perfectly when I run it.

My actual code look like this (I will only include the relevant parts) :

```
var tour1
var tour2
[...]
// Bootstrap tour

        //Create tour1
            tour1 = new Tour({
            storage: window.localStorage,
            debug: true,
            //add steps
            steps: [
                {
                path:"/base/show/1",
                element: "#home",
                title: "{{ 'tuto11 title' | trans }}",
                content: "{{ 'tuto11 desc' | trans }}",
                placement: "right"
            },
            {
                path:"/base/show/1",
                element: ".mce-item-table",
                placement: "top",
                title: "{{ 'tuto12 title' | trans }}",
                content: "{{ 'tuto12 desc' | trans }}"
            },
            {
                path:"/base/show/2124",
                element: ".titlepage",
                title: "{{ 'tuto13 title' | trans }}",
                content: "{{ 'tuto13 desc' | trans }}",
                placement: "top"
            },
            {
                path: "/base/show/2566",
                element: ".titlepage",
                title: "{{ 'tuto14 title' | trans }}",
                content: "{{ 'tuto14 desc' | trans }}",
                placement: "top"
            },
            {
                path: "/base/show/1093",
                element: ".titlepage",
                title: "{{ 'tuto15 title' | trans }}",
                content: "{{ 'tuto15 desc' | trans }}",
                placement: "top"
            },
            {
                path: "/base/show/1093",
                element: "h2", //h2 = pas bon
                title:"{{ 'tuto16 title' | trans }}",
                content:"{{ 'tuto16 desc' | trans }}",
                placement:"top"
            }
            ]
        });

        //Initialize the tour
        //tour1.init();

        //Create tour2
        {% if app.user %}
        tour2=new Tour({
            storage: window.sessionStorage,
            debug: true,
            //add steps
            steps: [
                {
                path: "/base/show/1",
                element: "#icProfil",
                title:"{{ 'tuto21 title' | trans }}",
                content:"{{ 'tuto21 desc' | trans }}",
                placement:"bottom"
            },
            {
                path: "/member/show/{{ app.user.getId()}}",
                element: ".titlepage",
                title:"{{ 'tuto22 title' | trans }}",
                content:"{{ 'tuto22 desc' | trans }}",
                placement: "top"
            },
            {
                path: "/member/show/{{ app.user.getId() }}",
                element: ".fa-icon-pencil",
                placement: "bottom",
                title:"{{ 'tuto23 title' | trans }}",
                content:"{{ 'tuto23 desc' | trans }}"

            },
            {
                path: "/member/edit/{{ app.user.getId() }}#civil",
                element: "#idn1",
                placement: "left",
                title: "{{ 'tuto24 title' | trans }}",
                content: "{{ 'tuto24 desc' | trans }}"
            },
            {
                path: "/member/edit/{{ app.user.getId() }}#social",
                element: "#idn2",
                placement: "left",
                title: "test",
                content: "test"
            }
            ]
        });

        tour2.init();
        {% endif %}

    })

    //Start the tours
    function startTour1(){
        tour1.restart();
    }

    function startTour2(){
        tour2.restart();
    }
```

**What I have tested :**
If I do not initialize the tour 2, the tour 1 works perfectly when StartTour1() is called.
I also tried to implement my start function like that :

```
function startTour2(){
            tour2.init();
            tour2.restart();
    }
```

In this case, the tour1 works great, but when the tour2 starts, it runs on the first step but when arriving to the 2nd step, I have this error message :

> Bootstrap Tour 'tour' | Redirect to /member/show/2072
>
> Bootstrap Tour 'tour' | Redirect to /base/show/1
>
> Bootstrap Tour 'tour' | Error redirection loop to /base/show/1

I haven't found any exemple of multi initializations in one page on the Internet, or any spec. about that in the doc.
Thanks by advance if you have any clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my mistake : The tours have a variable "name". By default it's defined as 'tour' , and if it's not overwritten, all the tours have the same name. If each tour has its own name, my code works perfectly.

Comment: They should definitely call this out more in the docs. Then again the docs are getting pretty stale by now. I've seen several outright mistakes.